# TypeError: table is null when adding row to table in datagridview bound data surce

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have DataGridView is data binding source from table in database

I wanna add rows programmatically when DataGridView is empty

i am using this code

```
        private void btn_add_Pax_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int number_of_pax = Convert.ToSByte(txt_Pax.Text);

            DataTable dt = dgvadministration.DataSource as DataTable;

            for (int i = 0; i <= number_of_pax; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row[1] =Convert.ToString(i);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

but get this error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' dt was null.

error show here

> DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

whey this dt always null

**Edit**
i wanna add number of pax , when user select number of pax >> add programmaticlly number of rows = number of pax like photo

**Note** session_Code in datagridview is number of pax
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfd1W.png)

and this is my class add to datagridview
BindingSource using entity frame work

```
public partial class V_Session_Data
    {
        public int C_Order_Serial_Code { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Session_Code { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Masseurs_Code { get; set; }
        public string Masseurs_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> Session_Type_Code { get; set; }
        public string Session__Type_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> C_Order_Masseurs { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Room_Number { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Session_date { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

create data table first Then add data table to datagridview surce

I'm using this method it's work fine

```
int number_of_pax = Convert.ToSByte(txt_Pax.Text);
               
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Your_Column");
 DataRow dr = null;

 for (int i = 0; i <= number_of_pax ; i++)
 {
     dr = dt.NewRow();
     dr["Your_Column"] = i.ToString();
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 }
    dgvadministration.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the object in `dgvadministration.DataSource` is not a DataTable.

Perhaps you set it like:

```
dgvadministration.DataSource = someDataTable.DefaultView;
```

in which case it's a `DataView`, which is not a datatable.

Perhaps you've never set it..

---

All in, we can't tell you what it is but the debugger can. When the program is stopped on the exception, dismiss/minimize the exception helper and point to `dgvadministration.DataSource` and the tooltip will tell you what kind of object it is:

[image]

Here I point to the DataSource and I can see it's a `{System.Data.DataView}` type. The screenshot is VB just because that's what I had open at the time but C# is the same. You'll only get a non null out of `as` if you `as` the datasource as what the object truly is, or one of the types from which is it descended

Comment: kind of object `dgvadministration.DataSource = { [System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource]}`

Comment: Mmm... a BindingSource being there kinda implies to me that you ARE "doing things properly", which then makes me think that, because this code you're writing in the question is NOT REALLY "doing things properly", the task you're seeking to accomplish should be done another way. I assume you're looking to create e.g. 5 blank rows in the grid and then get the user to fill them in?

Comment: yes i wanna add 5 blank rows or any number  and add data in Cell number [1] programmability using `for (int i = 0; i <= number_of_pax; i++)`  .. then user add The rest of cells using textboxs

Comment: What data do you want to add programmaticlly?

Comment: i wanna add number of pax , when user select number of pax >> add programmaticlly number of rows = number of pax 


example user select 3 pax ...
i wanna create 3 rows and cell [1] = ("1" , "2" , "3") ... i'm using for to do this `for (int i = 0; i <= number_of_pax; i++)`

Comment: like photo in question

Comment: I disagree with the approach, because it looks like you're just settings a couple of incrementing numbers programmatically; there isn't any need to do it in advance.. But if you want to do this, use a loop to add rows to the (probably strongly typed) datatable that the bindingsource is bound to. Show the full `bindingSource.DataSource =` (where *bindingSource* is the BindingSource the grid is bound to) code line plus the 5 lines above it for more help

Comment: how can i do this ?? please tell me What is changing in my code by edit  your Answer

Comment: i get max number of pax from databasie   and  pax ++ >>> so wanna using this method

Comment: It's ok, I know how to use SO, promise. I can't answer your question at the moment because you haven't provided all the info I asked for: *Show the full bindingSource.DataSource = (where bindingSource is the BindingSource the grid is bound to) code line plus the 5 lines above it for more help*. I need to know what kind of thing your bindingsource is bound to

Comment: i'm using entity framework , add class to datagridview 
i put class in question .....Is this what you want or something else ؟؟

Comment: Helpful, but doesn't show how it (a `List<V_Session_Data>` or similar) gets into the `BindingSource.DataSource`. Show the code where you set the datasource of the bindingsourcew